# Finding a specific polynomial function, with conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a polynomial such that $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 +dx^3 + ex^4$ such
> that $f(1)=1, f(2) = -1, f(-1)=5, f(3) = -59, f(-2) = -29$

Any hints on how to approach this? I was thinking about plugging in the f value and then the result in order to build a matrix like this, but I am not sure if that is what I am supposed to do here.

$\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & d & e & 1\\
a & -b & -c & -d & -e & -1\\
a & -b & -c & -d & -e & 5\\
a & 3b & 3c & 3d & 3e & -59\\
a & -2b & -2c & -2d & -2e & -29
\end{pmatrix}$

does this make any sense?

Comment: You should fill in value of x following each letter.

Comment: You could use Lagrange interpolation to get the polynomial.

Comment: I cannot identify $f(-2)=-1$ Your $\underline{\text{second row}}$ of your matrix is not right. It has to be $$a-2b+4c-8d+16e=-1$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(1)=1, f(2)=-1,f(-1)=5,f(3)=-59,f(-2)=-29$
Provided a linear $5\times 5$ sysytem of equation as $MV=U$
where $$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 &1 &1 &1 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 &-1 & 1\\ 1 & 3 & 9 & 27 & 81 \\ 1 & -2 & 4 & -8 & 16 \end{pmatrix}, V=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\\ c\\ d\\ e \end{pmatrix}, U =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 5 \\ -59 \\ -29 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Solving this equation by LinearSolve of Mathematica we get get $$V=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -5 \\ 4 \\ 3 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Finally, we get $f(x)=1-5x+4x^2+3x^3-2x^4.$

Mathe matica Command: LinearSolve[m,u]

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate f(1), f(2), f(-1), f(3) and f(-2) to find the coefficients.

f(1) = a+b+c+d+e = 1

f(2) = a+2b+4c+8d+16e = -1

f(-1) = a-b+c-d+e = 5

f(3) = a+3b+9c+27d+81e= -59

f(-2)= a-2b+4c-8d+16e = -29

Next we take the coefficients and the result and we put them in a matrix:

A=

| 1  1  1  1  1   |

| 1  2  4  8  16  |

| 1 -1  1 -1  1   |

| 1  3  9 27  81  |

| 1 -2  4 -8  16  |

C will be the matrix with the outputs:

| 1|

|-1|

| 5|

|-59|

|-29|

B will be the matrix with the letters:

|a|

|b|

|c|

|d|

|e|

Now we need to solve the matrix equation A*B=C.

But because in matrix algebra there is no division operation, we need to multiply both sides with the inverse of the matrix A. We will call the inverse A'. So the equation becomes:

(A')*(A)*(B) = (A')*(C)

Since A' is the inverse of A, (A')*(A)= I and I is the identity matrix(a matrix that when its multiplied by another one doesnt change the result) So the equation is:

(B)=(A')*(C)

So now we need to calculate the inverse, and multiply it by the matrix C, and those thats all. To do that there are multiple ways and honestly its been too long since high school. But i leave you with this link: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/systems-linear-equations-matrices.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!

$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c} 1&1&1&1&1&1\\ 1&2&4&8&16& -1\\ 1&-1&1&-1&1&5\\1&3&9&27&81&-59\\ 1&-2&4&-8&16&-29\end{array}\right)\simeq_{RREF} \left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}1&0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&0&0& -5\\ 0&0&1&0&0&4\\0&0&0&1&0&3\\ 0&0&0&0&1&-2\end{array} \right)$

thus $a=1,b=-5,c=4,d=3,e=-2$, and I used an RREF calculator to find the latter matrix.

The first matrix is the matrix representation of the $5$ equations with $5$ unknowns $a,b,c,d,e$:

$$\begin{align}a+b+c+d+e &=1\\
\\
a+2b+4c+8d+16e & =-1\\
\\
a-b+c-d+e &=5\\
\\
a+3b+9c+27d+81e &=-59\\
\\
a-2b+4c-8d+16e &=-29\end{align}$$

Note that in the matrix representation we are only interested in manipulating the coefficients of these $5$ equations, without having to rewrite $a,b,c,d,e$ multiple times, each column is representative of $a,b,c,d,e$ thus you don’t need to plug in $\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c} a&b&c&d&e&1\end{array}\right)$ for the first row, same for the other rows.

Check:

After plugging in the values of $a,b,c,d,e$
$$f(x)=1-5x+4x^2+3x^3-2x^4$$

and plugging in $x=1,2,-1,3,-2:$

$$f(1)=1-5+4+3-2= 1 \checkmark$$
$$f(2)=1-5(2) +4(2)^2 +3(2)^3-2(2)^4 = 1-10+16+24-32=-1\checkmark$$
$$f(-1)=1+5+4-3-2=10-5=5\checkmark$$
$$f(3)=1-5(3)+4(3)^2+3(3)^3-2(3)^4=1-15+36+81-162=22-81=-59\checkmark$$
$$f(-2)=1-5(-2)+4(-2)^2+3(-2)^3-2(-2)^4=1+10+16-24-32=-29\checkmark$$